# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\tf2\BPDumper.php on line 291

Tags: php, html, css

Supposedly it works on the mac version of xampp but to no prevail, I own a windows PC

The code: http://pastebin.com/zQ6JxHZe

Comment: Could be a short open tags difference in config between the two boxes

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part seems to be the problem:

```
function print_r_html( $arr )
{
    ?><pre><?
    print_r( $arr );
    ?></pre><?
}
```

You are not opening the PHP tags correctly. Try this instead:

```
function print_r_html( $arr )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $arr );
    echo '<pre>';
}
```

Comment: Is this because short tags are not enabled on the OP's server?

Comment: @MarcAudet It seems likely yes. This setting is off on my testing environment, and it gives me parse error. Removing the `<? ?>` fixes it.